# Jquery .append after retrieve a value from <select> with .on('change') don't work properly

Tags: jquery

I've a list of elements structured in this way:

```
<select id="simple_list">
 <option value="val1">Value</option>
 <option value="val2">Value</option> ...
```

I should put some html element in a div called **panel_content** strucured as follow:

```
<div id="panel_content" class="panel-content"></div>
```

jQuery to my rescue:

```
$('#simple_list').on('change', function() {

    var val = $(this).val();

    switch ( val ) {
        case 'val1':
            $('#panel_content').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < an_array.length; i++) {
                $('#panel_content').append('<p>' + an_array.places[i] + '</p>');
                console.log('Test');
            }
            break; ....
```

Note that console.log inside cycle is executed correctly, but in panel_content items are not included.

It seems that .append() is not executed.

Why?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? It would help to see a more complete example of your code, which includes the content of `an_array`

Comment: no errors in console. Array is placed in an object literal:  `var xxx = {
        name: "Something",
        places: ['Moon', 'Earth', 'Mars']
    }`

Comment: Is `#simple_list` deeply wrapped in anything? Sometimes jQuery requires more parent selectors as it will have trouble accessing the child. For example `$('div > div').on('#simple_list', 'change', function() {});`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but OP said that the `console.log` was executed so the loop is firing at least once

Comment: it's wrapped but I don't think so deeply, here's the parents structure: `<div class="super_parent">
                <form>
                    <p class="thomas-selector-list">
                        <label>Label: </label>
                        <select id="simple_list">`

Comment: @wmash I tried in jsfiddle and with the code as OP has specified it could not possibly be the case.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that is fair enough. Anyway, your solution given below is the correct one. +1

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `for` loop. Given the format of the `an_array` variable (which is actually an object), which you state in the comments to be like this:

> Array is placed in an object literal: var xxx = { name: "Something", places: ['Moon', 'Earth', 'Mars'] }

Then you need to iterate over the `places` property, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < an_array.places.length; i++) {
    $('#panel_content').append('<p>' + an_array.places[i] + '</p>');
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ovdxsqej/)